# Android - ActionBar fell below tabs after customizing background

Tags: android, android-actionbar

It seems that if I add tabs to the actionbar and then customize it somehow, the tabs come above the actionbar..

This happens when I:

- use custom background for actionbar
- attempt to remove actionbar title or icon
- use custom view for actionbar

Any solutions? I'm not using ActionbarSherlock

Comment: is your custom background a drawable?  9-patch?

Comment: no its a PNG, not 9-patch. But the point is that anything I do to the ActionBar brings the tabs above, whether I change the height or delete the title or change background.

Answer (score 0):

You can use android default action bar.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"
```

This will give you default action bar. Below code will add actionbar tabs.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        };

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab " + (i + 1))
                    .setTabListener(tabListener));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Finally to customize the background , you can refer the developers site 
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomBackground

Comment: What you write above is exactly what I do. Do you mean that if I use the native actionbar (instead of actionbarcompat) the problem will be solved?